# Pass the value of the int outside the OnClick method

Tags: java, android

So, I want all of those variables to get the value after going through the OnClick method. When I put the log in the method they are ok, but outside... I know that they destroy because it's OnClick method and they are local but I don't know how to keep them. Please if you know how to help rewrite the code. Thanks!

```
package com.exemple.android.calendar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class NewEventActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //step 1.A:create objects

    public EditText DayEditText;
    public EditText MonthEditText;
    public EditText YearEditText;
    public EditText StartingHourEditText;
    public EditText StartingMinuteEditText;
    public EditText EndingHourEditText;
    public EditText EndingMinuteEditText;
    public EditText Title;
    public RadioGroup answer1;
    public Button NewEventButton;

    int day, month, year, s_hour, s_min, e_hour, e_min;
    String title;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_event_page);

        //Step 1.B: assign objects

        DayEditText = findViewById(R.id.DayEditText);
        MonthEditText = findViewById(R.id.MonthEditText);
        YearEditText = findViewById(R.id.YearEditText);
        StartingHourEditText = findViewById(R.id.StartingHourEditText);
        StartingMinuteEditText = findViewById(R.id.StartingMinuteEditText);
        EndingHourEditText = findViewById(R.id.EndingHourEditText);
        EndingMinuteEditText = findViewById(R.id.EndingMinuteEditText);
        Title = findViewById(R.id.TitleEditText);
        answer1 = findViewById(R.id.Answer1);
        NewEventButton = findViewById(R.id.CreateEventButton);

        //Step 2: get data into variables

        //Step 2.B: get data and assign
        //PROBLEM: If we just extract, the code won't be run because there's nothing to extract yet. We need a conditional.
        //SOLUTION: Create a condition for pressing the button, and then extract the variables when the button is pressed.

        NewEventButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                title = Title.getText().toString();
                day = Integer.parseInt(DayEditText.getText().toString());
                month = Integer.parseInt(MonthEditText.getText().toString());
                year = Integer.parseInt(YearEditText.getText().toString());
                s_hour = Integer.parseInt(StartingHourEditText.getText().toString());
                s_min = Integer.parseInt(StartingMinuteEditText.getText().toString());
                e_hour = Integer.parseInt(EndingHourEditText.getText().toString());
                e_min = Integer.parseInt(EndingMinuteEditText.getText().toString());


            }
        });
        Log.i("INFO:",title+" "+day+" "+month+" "+year+" "+s_hour+" "+s_min+" "+e_hour+" "+e_min);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct, it is just a understanding issue.

In fact, it's normal the `Log` method prints nothing because your variables are not set. The code inside the `OnClick` is called **only** if a click happens. Then, when click happens, your variables are set correctly.

Understood ?

Here is an example of `TextWatcher`

```
DayEditText = findViewById(R.id.DayEditText);
DayEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        day = Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
    }
});
```

Do the same for each EditTexts you have

Comment: Well, what I want to do is to get the values even if the button isn't pressed. But then the activity wouldn't work at all and it crashes. Any ideas?

Comment: Then, you have to use `TextWatcher` on your `EditText` to catch the text changes https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher

Comment: Could you please rewrite the code? I tried with it and I think I'm getting it wrong... Anyway, thank you!